# Retain value of a mat-select in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a mat-select field. Values of mat-select field are populated from an array.
When I select another item in the drop-down a dialog-box with OK and Cancel buttons will be displayed. When I select OK then the item which i selected 
 will be set as selected item. Other wise the previous item 
needs to set as selected item.
Currently, I could not take the previous item. If I made a selection that will be set as selected item.

html

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCar" fxFlex="12.5rem" 
  (selectionChange)="onCarChange(selectedCar)" id="slctselectedCar">
 <mat-option *ngFor="let carName of carNames" [value]="carName">
    {{carName}}  
 </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

.ts file

```
carNames:string[]=["Toyota","Honda"];  

public onCarChange(selectedCar): void{
  console.log(selectedCar);
}
```

Comment: take a variable to store the last selected value and maintain new one as latest value with another variable.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you need something like this:

```
  public onCarChange(selectedCar): void {
       this.possibleSelectedItem = selectedCar;

       // dialog box code here

       // if OK then this.selectedItem = this.possibleSelectedItem
       // if Cancel, do nothing and selected item will remain the previous one
  }
```

*you could do it without `this.possibleSelectedItem` but maybe it is easier to understand like this.*

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5frct4) is a StackBlitz example, without the dialog box code

Comment: this.possibleSelectedItem = selectedCar; have the newly selected value. How can I resolve this?

Comment: the previous value (selected a step before) is stored in `this.selectedValue`